# unexpected `server_admin required` error with Cloudant NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am using the Cloudant service via the Node.JS module, with the credentials provided via Bluemix VCAP_SERVICES (or a local copy). The instance is created with

```
var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
// var cloudantCreds obtained from process.env.VCAP_SERVICES
var username = cloudantCreds.username;
var password = cloudantCreds.password;
var cloudant = Cloudant({
    account:username, 
    password:password
});
```

I had written a function that would automatically create/delete a database when a user requested, and it successfully worked. This internally used

```
cloudant.db.create(databaseName, function(err, res){
     // Handle
});
```

However, recently I get an error:

```
'server_admin access is required for this request'
```

I am only using one set of credentials and one account. Using these credentials in the command line with curl allows me to successfully create/delete databases, but it seems to be unable to do this via the node.js module?

As far as I can remember, I haven't changed any code related to this function of my Node.js server.

What is causing me to now require server_admin access? From the nature of the error message, I am presumably authenticated, but not authorised?

Comment: I have just executed your code snippet with my admin account/password and I was able to create a new database from the Node.js application. 

When I swapped the credentials for a non-admin apikey/password I get `server_admin access is required for this request`. 

You can debug the request that is actually being made by doing:

`DEBUG=nano node app.js`

i.e. setting the `DEBUG` environment variable to `nano`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about DEBUG, it helps.

It appears that the issue is not with the functionality I've described above  - that it turns out still works as expected in deployment. I get the error when running Mocha tests on the express object that triggers the above function, so presumably there is an error somewhere in the mocha set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was an error on my behalf, although Cloudant was not particularly informative.

I was trying to create databases with disallowed names, such as beginning with an underscore or containing a capital letter. Change the database name, and it all works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if your database is prefixed with underscore it will throw errors...

Comment: Can you differentiate your answer from the existing answer which gives the exact same information?